# Nested forms with triggers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a product configurator with several business rules. 
I have two models, one is product, the second is component. a product has many components, but the 
same component could be used in different products.

I have the models and relations etc, and trying to build my show view in the product controller

--in controller

```
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@productelements = Product.find(params[:id]).elements
end
```

--in view

```
<% @productelements.each do |p| %>
   <li><%= p.name </li> 
   <li><%= p.quantity </li> 
<% end %>
```

So far so good, except it needs to hold certain rules. This is to be able to configure 
products like computers. Quantities are user defined (in some cases) but they might affect
other elements. For example if I have the following:

```
 Element    Quantity
 Processor A    1
 RAM in GB      2
 HDD Type B     2
```

User can change the processor to processor B, but in this case the quantity of the HDD will need to change to 1. This is just to illustrate.

So I'm trying to figure out how to:
- Wrap this looping through elements into a form.
- Make the form responsive to changes and call a function which would validate and adjust where needed.
- render the product with the validated fields.

Any advice you can give me? Or maybe the approach is not at all realistic?
Mind there's many products and many rules, so I didn't want to make case statements inside the controller as it would drag for miles!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, to first correct the above code a bit, you're searching for the same Product twice needlesly. Instead of your first code block, do this:

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @productelements = @product.elements
end
```

As you can see, I've replaced the second find() call.

Now to your bigger question, I think you're overthinking this. If there are business rules tied to components, express those in a module stuck into the lib/ directory and mix that module into the Product model. This way, you'll be able to test the business rules outside of the context of a form, to ensure you got it just right.

Then you can use said tested rules as custom validation on the form. So, in your example, if the user changes CPU A to CPU B, but leaves the HDD in an incorrect quantity, the backend validation will catch and flag this.

You can then expose this validation through ajax to the front-end for a slicker UI, but one thing at a time.

Make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot! I'm a bit concerned over the following, I don't necessarily want the user to enter the required quantity on HDDs, but rather adjust myself any fields that depend upon changes. As such, I understand the only way to do this would be over javascript using the tags from the form. But this again, leaves all my configuration rules exposed to anyone who can see the source code of the page. Is there anyway to make the form call an action upon change, and render again, but this time without querying the db? Otherwise I would end up getting the same default view?

Comment: Since your business rules would live in the module, not the database, you can easily make an ajax call to adjust the values based on the value of a field you just left. This way, it won't be on the client-side and you won't have to query the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Srdjan. Is there any good resource you could recommend to see how this is done? I mean the ajax call to a module method and results?

Comment: Not really, but it shouldn't be too hard. Think of your validation rules as a resource. You can, for example, create a validations controller, which you would use the same as any other controller. The actions in this controller would call your module as opposed to an ActiveRecord model.